# PHP Memory Limit Issues

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7, cpanel

hey guys i have a problem running Meagento commands setup & compile because of memory limit it's 256.

i have requested from the hosting company to increase my memory limit to 1024MB and they did. i can see the change on php.ini file at root folder in cpanel.

but when i ran the commands i got the same errors again of memory limit so i checked the limit with

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

i found that it is still 256MB. Is there any place where in my Magento that this limit is saved ???

any help please i'm stuck

Comment: No,magento does not save memory_limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these command:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: like a charm. thank you so much i had no idea that i could increase memory with each command ..... thanks again

Answer (score 3):

When you run

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

you are not initializing magento at all.

It is possible, that your hoster increased memory limit for your webserver, but not for cli (which you are running here).