# Increasing php limit to 756 MB in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

When I tried to install new modules it shows a error that says

> "Your current PHP memory limit is 256M. Magento 2 requires it to be
>   set to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini
>   file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where
>   it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again."

I edited php.ini file but it didn't work. It also contains a **php.ini.sample** file in root. I have a shared hosting plan and hosting  provider says they won't increase php limit size from their side in case of Shared hosting plan. Someone please help me. What should I do?

Comment: As of now, ask them to restart the server. Its time to think about changing your hosting plan :)

Comment: @MGento I found the same question and I think they've solved the problem. Please follow the link for the question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188220/php-memory-limit-issues/188236#188236 ". Someone advised to run few command lines but I don't know how to run them . Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you hitting this issue when you are trying to compile you could always try using:

php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile